# AngularJS filter with trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a custom filter that replaces new lines with `<br/>`, like this:

```
angular.module('appFilters', []).filter('break_lines', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(input) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(input.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
  };
}]);
```

And use it in a template like this:

```
<div class="home-tag">{{locales.home_tagline | break_lines}}</div>
```

The problem is that the resulting text is html escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="home-tag" ng-bind-html="(locales.home_tagline | break_lines)"></div>
```

Hope it helps